# JavaScript promises beginner

Tags: javascript, promise

I have been trying to learn promises recently, but I am hitting a roadblock? any suggestions: Can you tell me, what I am doing wrong here?

```js
function printstring(string) {
  return new promise( function (resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.write(string);
      resolve();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;)
  })
}

function printall() {
  printstring("A")
    .then(function () { return printString("C"); })
}

printall();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of typos in your code.

- `promise` should be `Promise` with capital `P`
- `printString("C")` should be `printstring("C")`
- `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;)` should be `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);`

If you want to observe how `setInterval` together with `Promise` works in this case then increase its delay (although it works just fine with any value).

```js
function printstring(string) {
  return new Promise( function (resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.write(string);
      resolve();
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
  })
}

function printall(){
  printstring("A")
    .then(function () { return printstring("C"); })
}
printall();
```

Just a small note, avoid using `document.write(string);`, it is really an old style way of placing content to your website. Instead use something like `innerHTML` or `textContent`. In this particular case, you could replace that line with `document.body.textContent += string;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function printstring(string) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject)=> {
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    console.log(string);
                    resolve();
                }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);

        })
    }

    function printall() {

        printstring("A")
            .then(function () {
                return printstring("C");
            })

    }
    printall();




    Better use Es6 arrow functions.this makes your code cleaner.
  i was using node so replaced document.write with console.log
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating an instance of Promise, you're doing it in lower case, should be `new Promise` not `new promise`.

Comment: why do in this case my code sometimes prints C before A.                            
function printstring(string)
     {
      return new Promise (  (resolve,reject) => {
       setTimeout( 
       function () {
       document.write(string) ;
       resolve();
       }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
       );
      }
     )}
     
     function printall(){
     
      printstring("A")
      .then( printstring("C"))
     
     }
     printall();      @guru

Comment: Because you're calling `setTimeout` at a random amount of time, so maybe when it's first called, it has a timeout that is longer than the time of the second call of `printall()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printString(string){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.write(string);
            resolve();
        }, Math.floor(Math.round() * 100) +1)
    })
}

function printAll(){
    printString("Test").then(function(res){
        printString("<br>sample<br>");
    })
}

printAll();
```

promise should be Promise (Start with Capital P) see doc [Promise in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)